# What does "@" mean in dart - flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does the `@` in the terminal referring to ?

```
class NumberTriviaLocalDataSourceImpl implements NumberTriviaLocalDataSource {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;  // use ? for solving the error 

  NumberTriviaLocalDataSourceImpl({@required this.sharedPreferences});
  // With null safety, use the 'required' keyword, not the '@required' annotation. Try removing the '@'.
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/language/metadata

Comment: There are keywords, like `required`, and there are annotations, like `@required`.

Comment: Before null-safety, there was a `@required` *annotation* that provided a *hint* to the analyzer that an argument should be required.  With null-safety, a proper `required` *keyword* was added to the language itself, and you should use that instead. The message from the analyzer tells you what to do: remove the `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart and Flutter, the "@" symbol is a syntax for metadata. When declaring things like classes, methods, and variables, metadata can be used to give the Dart compiler additional information or instructions.
Here is link to dart documentation https://dart.dev/language/metadata